# "Главное"

Tags: пунктуация

"Главное(,) я не знаю, куда идти" - тут "главное" отделяется запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ДА, в данном предложении слово "главное" - вводное. Оно не связано грамматически с другими словами (нельзя задать вопрос к слову "главное"). Слово "главное" может быть и членом предложения. Прочитайте с ударением на этом слове: главного я не знаю (не знаю чего? главного). Какой Вам случай подходит по замыслу, тот и выбирайте.